# How do you make a Java app with a Cocoa UI?

Tags: java, xcode, cocoa, user-interface

I have to use a Java API for a project, but since I'm not a fan of Java UIs and I have a Mac, I want to build a native Cocoa application around the Java code. I know Xcode used to provide direct support for this sort of thing, but since it no longer does, what's the best way to do this?
If it matters, I have Xcode 3.2.5 under Mac OS 10.6.8.

Comment: About the only thing that comes to mind is having your Java code use JNI to talk to Cocoa / Carbon code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this Apple [tech note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2147/_index.html) it should be possible to launch a JVM from within your native Mac application. This article was originally written in 2006 and a lot has changed since then with Apple's support for Java. However, it does look like the article was updated this year so perhaps it is still supported in current versions of the OS? I can't vouch for it but it does seem like its worth a try.

Comment: Considering that the JVM is written in C++ and has to compile for linux, windows and mac os, nothing special about that there. But then you don't need (makes it a bit simpler though) the GUI in the same process and there are native widgets out there.

Comment: I am currently looking into the same thing and would like to ask: Did it work?

Comment: This is true! IntelliJ for example uses a native macOS launcher that initialized the JVM!

Answer (score 4):

You can use any Cocoa API through this [Java-Objective-C bridge](http://solutions.weblite.ca/java-objective-c-bridge/docs/).  Unlike Rococoa, it doesn't require you to generate a whole bunch of Java class stubs before you begin.  It is a small dynamic wrapper over the Objective-C runtime that allows you to send messages to Cocoa objects.

Comment: If you're going to promote your own product, you need to include a disclaimer in your answer to say so.

Comment: Unfortunately, while it still works really well, it is pretty painful to use and the methods do not always come back correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible using XCode.  However, it is possible to create GUIs using [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), which uses native widgets.

However, I don't really do GUI apps in Java, so I don't know if there are any GUI designers that use SWT, although it appears that [WindowBuilder Pro for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html) does.

Comment: WindowBuilder is practically the best GUI builder for Java anyhow, so nothing to lose there.

Comment: Yeah, but that would still be a Java-based GUI. I want to call Java code from a native GUI, without messing about with SWT or Swing or anything; is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can call almost any Cocoa API through [rococoa](http://code.google.com/p/rococoa/), though it will not necessarily be fast or clean.